# Is there a tool like Dependency Walker that can be run on a Windows CE 6.5 mobile device?

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I am trying to port an application from eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 to Visual Studio 2008, and trying to get it to work with a Windows Embeded Handheld (6.5 Professional).

I have the compiler errors all fixed, but now I am runnning into an error that pops up when VS2008 trys to run debug mode on the deployed exe on the device. I am getting the error: `Unable to start program '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\APP_NAME\APP.exe'. An error occurred that usually indicates a corupt installation (code 0x8007007e). If the problem persists, repair your visual studio installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in your Control Panel`

This is evidently an error associated with missing DLL files, which I have found and fixed a couple, but there seems to be more. I was wondering if there was a tool like Dependency Walker that can be run on a Windows CE 6.5 mobile device. It would make finding missing DLLs much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that is really a dependency problem you will find it on device running PEInfo (Freeware: http://s-k-tools.com/index.html?m_util.html). Copy/install PEInfo to device and then start it and select File/Open and open the exe file. PEInfo checks the imports and verifies the load of the referenced DLLs (is loadable). PEInfo is really a good freeware tool to anlyze such load problems.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I was looking for and more.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one that I'm aware of, but depends.exe on the desktop can inspect device files.  It usually gets confused when it hits the coredll.dll dependency, but you know that coredll has no dependencies on anything else, so it's a non-issue.

Comment: I tried to do this already, and it does not run. Are there any settings I have to do to get it to work? I will give it another try.

edit: it says all the dlls are missing, but i know that at least some of them are on the device.

Comment: To be clear, you use the desktop (depends.exe or depency walker both work) app *on the desktop* and it can inspect device DLLs.

Comment: I use dumpbin /exports or http://www.safer-networking.org/products/filealyzer/ to see the imports of a DLL or exe. Regardless of being a desktop or Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 file. You KNOW that there is no Windows CE 6.5!

Comment: Dependency Walker won't be able to look into CE's Windows folder and it won't magically find things anywhere else on the device either, just those in the folder where the DLL/EXE is that it is run on.